# Using Always Encrypted with Entity Framework and Azure Key Vault

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I've encrypted some columns in an Azure SQL Database, using [Always Encrypted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/mt163865.aspx) and a column master key stored in an Azure Key Vault, but I'm having trouble accessing them from my application using Entity Framework.

There's a recent [MSDN article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-always-encrypted-azure-key-vault/) and an [older blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/11/10/using-the-azure-key-vault-key-store-provider-for-always-encrypted/) that explain how to set up a SqlConnection to use Always Encrypted with an Azure Key Vault, so I'm guessing that a normal DbContext could be created using the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696604(v=vs.113).aspx) that accepts a `DbConnection`.

The problem is that I'm using an `IdentityDbContext`, which doesn't have that constructor - the only [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identitydbcontext.identitydbcontext(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext.) that takes a `DbConnection` also takes a `DbCompiledModel`, which is beyond my pay-grade at the moment.

Can anyone explain how to set up an `IdentityDbContext` to use the Key Vault?

Comment: I'm investigating ... found a mention of adding "Column Encryption Setting=Enabled" in ConnectionString, and the need to add a SqlParameter for an encrypted column. Here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-always-encrypted/#strongimportantstrong Are you encrypting a column or the whole database?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that EF team have a [test that uses encryption](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/f732e3c7c1a680a944b9aafaf34bef88ed8a19c4/test/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.FunctionalTests/SqlAzure/SqlAzureConnectionTest.cs).

```
var connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(SqlServerTestStore.CreateConnectionString("adventureworks"))
{
    Encrypt = encryptionEnabled
};
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
options.UseSqlServer(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);

using (var context = new AdventureWorksContext(options.Options))
{
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    Assert.Equal(ConnectionState.Open, context.Database.GetDbConnection().State);
}
```

TODO: test IdentityDbContext Constructor exposes same constructor as AdventureWorksContext.